# Getting movie lists and rating from two tables MySQL LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

I have a table

**movies**

```
movie_id
movie_name
language
cast
```

**ratings**

```
id
movie_id
rating
comment
```

I need to fetch all movies details with average and total count of ratings.

If there is no rating for any movie, average rating and total ratings count must be zero.

for this i tried this MySQL query:

```
SELECT m.movie_id,movie_name,cast,language,AVG(rating) as average_rating,COUNT(rating) as total_rating 
FROM movies m 
LEFT JOIN ratings r ON m.movie_id=r.movie_id;
```

But this query not giving all movies lists from 'movies' table.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: try addng groupby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `group by` with `movie_id` so it will differentiate your result with unique movie_id.

```
SELECT m.movie_id,m.movie_name,m.cast,m.language,AVG(r.rating) as average_rating,COUNT(r.rating) as total_rating 
FROM movies m 
LEFT JOIN ratings r ON m.movie_id=r.movie_id
GROUP BY m.movie_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add GROUP BY m.movie_id

```
SELECT
    `m`.`movie_id`, `m`.`movie_name`, `m`.`cast`, `m`.`language`,
    AVG(`r`.`rating`) `average_rating`, COUNT(`r`.`rating`) `total_rating`
FROM
    `movies` `m`
LEFT JOIN
    `ratings` `r`
ON
    `m`.`movie_id` = `r`.`movie_id`
GROUP BY
    `m`.`movie_id`;
```